# MaxIf with associated row info?

Tags: excel, array-formulas

Im using array formulas to determine the maximum value of a specific subset of row data:

```
=MAX(($A2:$A100="somestring")*($C2:$C100))
```

This works fine & gets me the maximum value in C where A = "somestring".

Now, I want to return other column values associated with this "max" row that are strings.  Intuitively I think I may need to ditch the boolean logic multiplication strategy since string values are getting involved.  What's the best/cleanest way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(B1:B100,MATCH(MAX((A1:A100="somestring")*(C1:C100)),(A1:A100="somestring")*(C1:C100),0))
```

Column you want values for is set to B in this example.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're interested in the string in column D, this will work:

```
=INDEX(($D$1:$D$100),MAX(($A2:$A100="somestring")*(ROW($C2:$C100))))
```

Note that since it's Indexing on the Row() you're Index column needs to start at 1, e.g., D1:D100.

Comment: I think this returns the max Row that has "somestring" in column A, not the max value in column C.

Comment: On the right track, but I believe this is returning the maximum row number where the string matches, not the row number containing the max value in $C:$C100.

Comment: @  Excellll and DeafLeopard, right you are, misread the question.