# Return last date something was entered into one column with criteria from another column

Tags: excel-formula

I'm working with a set of data in excel. Data is entered into rows for items specified in columns. The first column contains a date. A cell in the same row of one of the columns contains the name of a person and in another cell in the same row but different column may contain a number larger than zero (or it may be empty).
I need to create a formula which returns the date when a number larger than zero was last entered into that column for a specific name. This is a "living list" which keeps on growing and the same names appear in different rows, sometimes with a number in the column a mentioned and sometimes not.
I found an old thread on this site on a similar subject which got me as far as knowing the date of the last entry containing the persons name but I'm still not able to configure it to show me when that specific person also had a number larger than zero in that column.
Here's the thread: [How to get the newest value from a column with conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597788/how-to-get-the-newest-value-from-a-column-with-conditions)

My current formula looks like this:

`=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(MAX(IF($G:$G=Sheet7!C5,$A:$A,0)),IF($G:$G=Sheet7!C5,$A:$A,"")))`
<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

Column A contains the dates 
Column G contains the names (and "Sheet7!C5" is a reference to a name)
The value column I need to add to the mix is column AY

I feel there must be a simple solution (a small add on to the formula) to solve this but I always end up with an error.

Thanks in advance :)

Edit: Here is a simplified example of the data entry and output list needed. [image: Data and output example]

Comment: Can you give a sample of simple example?

Comment: Hi Vylix, I've attached a pic of a simplified data table and output list. I have the sample at hand as an excel file but didn't see an option to attach such a file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to sort the date <strike>**DESCENDING**</strike> and format the table as **Excel Table**

**Edit:** you can sort the date ascending. See explanation at the end.

Using your example, then the formula will be

```
=INDEX(TableData[Activity A], MATCH($B14, TableData[Employee initials], 0))
```

This works just like the usual `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX MATCH`, fetching the *first* date on an activity matching the employee initials.

You can use `VLOOKUP`, but you'll need to [dynamically name the range](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html) of each columns.

**Edit:** Just today I found an interesting behavior of `MATCH` when it found multiple matching values. If you use `1` instead of `0`, then it will fetch the ***last*** matching value on the list.

So, you can use this formula instead in ASCENDING table.

```
=INDEX(TableData[Activity A], MATCH($B14, TableData[Employee initials], 1))
```

Comment: Thank you Vylix. Unfortuantely the table needs to be sorted in ascending order due to the fact that other users will keep adding to it (an said users are not skilled in excel so I don't want them to have to insert lines and drag formulas - there is much more data and formulas in the entry table than my simple example shows). Thus the latest date needs to be at the bottom of the table and somehow I need to be able to pull the latest date per user from it. I appreciate your help, if you have another solution which doesn't require descending order it would really make my day :)

Comment: @Frida I just recently discovered interesting behavior of `MATCH`. Updated the answer and I hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks Vylix. Am still having trouble with this after having formatted the table as Excel Table. Would you be able to write out the underlying cells from the data table in my example (e.g. instead of "TableData[Acitivity A]" write C2:C10). I've tried different selections but still get a zero as a result. I don't see how the column containing the date comes into play? I don't care if the number of Activity A is zero, one, two etc.. at the last data entry but I need to know the date of when there was last an entry (greater than zero) for said employee. Perhaps I wasn't clear on that in my Q.